# How long can a transmission line with proper impedance matched be routed?

Tags: usb, transmission-line

Would like to know the maximum length that I could route a transmission line for USB3.0 (SuperSpeed differential lines) and USB2.0 (DP/DM) in a proper impedance matched line at 90 ohms?

There is some documentation that mentioned about 8 inches, but in general what determines the maximum length for USB or any impedance matched transmission line?

Answer (score 2):

> *in general what determines the maximum length for USB or any
> impedance matched transmission line?*

Once an impedance line is matched, end-point reflections are minimal and so, the maximum length is then determined by the attenuation of the signal and the capabilities of the receiver to work with an attenuated signal that may be many decibels below what was transmitted.

There are other factors that might degrade this such as interference from other circuits. This is why we use differential transmission lines and differential receivers (because they are less susceptible to interference).

Comment: Thanks Andy. Perhaps then we will have to try routing it and see the results of it. I wonder will USB3.0 actually negotiate and settled for the best speed like Display Port?

Comment: @kakiitek no, USB3 will work or not work.